# bash script, list all the files over a specific size

Tags: bash, shell

so I have some code like this:

```
result=`find . -type f -size -1000c -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Sh | head`

for i in $result; do
    item=`wc -c $i`
    echo $item1 
done
```

this will print out all the files in the current fold that are at most 1000bytes, it has the format like:

size_of the file   ./name_of_the_file

but i want to get rid of the "./" symbol, so i try to use "cut"

i want to do something like:

```
for i in $result; do
    item=`wc -c $i`
    item1=`cut -f 1 $item`    // this gives me the size 
    item2=`cut -c 7- $item`   // this gives me all the character after ./ 
    echo item1, item2         // now make it print 
done
```

but i'm getting error like:

**`cut: 639: No such file or directory`**

can anyone please give me a hint on this? I appreciate it.

Comment: The argument to `cut` is a filename. `$item` isn't a filename, it's a filename with the size in bytes before it.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, thank you for your reply. Our instructor ask us to use "wc" and "cut" command. So it there anyway i can make it work with "cut" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `cut` when you can use `bash` variable expansion operators.

```
for i in $result; do
    i=$(echo $i | cut -c3-) # remove ./ prefix
    size=$(wc -c < $i)
    echo $size, $i
done
```

To use `cut` with a variable, you have to echo the variable to a pipe, because `cut` processes a file or stdin (like most Unix filters).

By redirecting the `wc` input instead of giving the filename as an argument, it just prints the size, not the size and the filename, so there's no need to cut its output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more concise:

```
find ./ -type f -size -1000c  -ls | sed -e 's/\.\///' | awk -e '{ print $7, $11 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
for i in $result; do
    item=`wc -c $i`
    item1=`echo $item | cut -d" " -f1`    // this gives me the size 
    item2=`echo $item | cut -d" " -f2-`   // this gives me all the charac...
    echo $item1, $item2         // now make it print 
done
```

As Barmar mentioned, you were passing the entire string to cut. Using the -d option can specify what character you split the string on, so assuming the size is separated from the remainder of the info by at least a space, the above should yield an $item1 and $item2 as you wanted.

Comment: You're not removing the `./` prefix